# How to access pixels of an NSBitmapImageRep?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pointers, image-manipulation, core-graphics

I have an `NSBitmapImageRep` that is created like this:

```
NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] 
                              initWithBitmapDataPlanes:NULL
                                            pixelsWide:waveformSize.width
                                            pixelsHigh:waveformSize.height
                                         bitsPerSample:8
                                       samplesPerPixel:4
                                              hasAlpha:YES
                                              isPlanar:YES
                                        colorSpaceName:NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace
                                           bytesPerRow:0
                                          bitsPerPixel:0];
```

Now I want to access the pixel data so I get a pointer to the pixel planes using

```
unsigned char *bitmapData;
[imageRep getBitmapDataPlanes:&bitmapData];
```

According to [the Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBitmapImageRep_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBitmapImageRep/getBitmapDataPlanes:) this returns a C array of five character pointers. But how can it do that? since the type of the argument is `unsigned char **`, it can only return an array of `char`s, but not an array of `char` *pointers*.

So, this leaves me wondering how to access the individual pixels. Do you have an idea how to do that?

(I know there is the method `– setColor:atX:y:`, but it seems to be pretty slow if invoked for every single pixel of a big bitmap.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to iterate over the pixels, -bitmapData should be all you need.

Comment: that only returns a pointer to the first plane. For a planar image this means I only can access the red color values… So you are suggesting to use a nonplanar image instead?

Answer (score 0):

> According to the Documentation this returns a C array of five character pointers. But how can it do that? since the type of the argument is `unsigned char **`, it can only return an array of chars, but not an array of char pointers.

Incorrect. `unsigned char **` is a pointer to at least one pointer to at least one `unsigned char`.

So, you're supposed to pass a pointer to an array of pointers—that is, a pointer to an array of arrays. Something like this:

```
unsigned char *buffers[5];
[bitmapImageRep getBitmapDataPlanes:buffers];
```

If the image rep is planar, then each element of `buffers` will be a pointer to a component plane; for RGB, `buffers[0]` is the red plane, `buffers[1]` is the green plane, `buffers[2]` is the blue plane, and `buffers[3]` is the alpha plane. Each plane is, of course, a buffer holding the values for that channel (as `unsigned char`s).

If the image rep is not planar, then you'll get only one element, which is the RGBA data.

Of particular note is this sentence from the documentation you linked to:

> If there are less than five planes, the remaining pointers will be set to `NULL`.

This means that the code you show contains a buffer overflow: You're passing a pointer to storage for one pointer, but the image rep expects storage for no fewer than five, and it *will* give you five pointers and/or `NULL`s, so it will be writing beyond the end of the storage you gave it. This will smash your stack, crash your application, or both.

Comment: so each whole plain is represented as a single `unsigned char`? That is one mighty `unsigned char` to hold some several thousand pixels. My question is: How is it feasible to save several thousand pixels in eight bit?

Comment: Paperflyer: No. Re-read the declaration: `unsigned char *buffers[5]` is an array of five pointers, each being a pointer to *at least one* `unsigned char`. Each plane is an array of `unsigned char`s. You get an array of five pointers to up to five arrays.